# SharePoint Workflow to create a task from email with attachment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

On SharePoint 2016 (on-prem), I have a library which receives emails.
I have created a workflow that creates a new task in a task list when a new email is received at the library.

My question is how can I attach the original email to the created task?

Alternatively, I can be happy if I can present the link to the original document and not to attach it.
In the task list i created a column called "Original Email" and in the workflow I am setting this column to be "Workflow Context:Current Item URL" when I create the task, but it shows the link in this format:
http://.../DropOffLibrary/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=26
and not to the original document but to the displayform of the item.

So, 2 questions in this thread - 1. Can I attach the original email to the new task 2. Can I display the exact link to the item and not to the display form?

[image: From the SharePoint Designer]

Thank you very much,
Effy.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you cannot attach the original email to the Task item using a SharePoint workflow.
2. Instead of using "Workflow Context:Current Item URL", I suggest you use "Current Item:URL Path", like the below:
   [image]